# Postgres regex string matching

Tags: regex, postgresql

How would I find address records the do not contain a digit followed by a space? (eg., 15SMith St. as opposed to 15 Smith St)

```
WHERE a.address not like '.[0-9] .'
```

is clearly not working for me.

Comment: What about `WHERE a.address NOT SIMILAR TO '%[0-9] %'`?

Comment: Perfect! Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`SIMILAR TO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP) with `NOT` and a pattern that is a "a curious cross between LIKE notation and common regular expression notation". It supports `[0-9]`:

> A bracket expression `[...]` specifies a character class, just as in POSIX regular expressions.

So, you may use

```
WHERE a.address NOT SIMILAR TO '%[0-9] %'
```

Here, `%` matches any number of any chars, `[0-9]` matches any digits, a space matches a space and then `%` again matches any number of any chars. These `%` are necessary because `SIMILAR TO` requires a full string match, same as `LIKE`.